# How to avoid electrical tape becoming lose

Tags: cables, tape

The low voltage side of my charger cable needed a layer of electrical tape because the outer insulation became brittle. This works fine most of the year, but during summer when the sun is shining on my desk, the end of the electrical tape starts to get loose.

I can't shrink wrap because the plug is rather big and a shrink wrapper large enough to fit over the plug won't shrink enough.

Is there any hack to prevent the end of the electrical tape from getting loose?

[image]

Comment: If the insulation is brittle, it could still deteriorate _inside_ your wrapping and cause a short.   If possible (and I know it might not be) replace the cord.

Comment: @SteveWellens Thanks for your comment. The insulation of the wires inside the cable seems to be unaffected. (replacing is not so easy, the computer manufacturer changed the shape of their plug twice since then and they don't sell this charger any longer :( )

Comment: "paint" it all up with clear nail polish, you can get it for $1. You can also simply chop the cable to get heat-shrink around it.

Comment: @dandavis It is not an USB cable. It is a non-standardised charger cable directly connected to the power adaptor box - nothing that can be simply replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that helps is to wrap it fairly tight, except for the last 1-2 turns which shouldn't be stretched.  This is much better than pulling it all tight, and a little better than not pulling any of it tight.

However if you've done this already, you'll need another option:

- A better brand of tape might be enough - some are very bad even new, others deteriorate quickly.
- You can secure the loose end with a small cable tie (zip tie), but I'd put a new layer of tape on top first.  Cut a piece about 3cm/1" long, lay the cable across the middle and bring the ends together, trimming if the overlap isn't perfect.  This is also good for labelling.
- A flag-shape piece of tape joins sticky side to sticky side.
  Of course these last 2 both end up with something sticking out
- You can also space out heatshrink, by slitting some that will fit over the cable and not the plug, placing that round the cable, and then some bigger heatshrink over the top, that will pass over the plug before shrinking.  Instead of the inner slit heatshrink, expandable braided cable sleeving can be used, but don't try to use tape for bulking up, it doesn't like the heat.

Answer (score 1):

Cover the loose end with Sugru, which is a moldable glue that hardens and becomes non-sticky

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called Bondic in the market that may be an ideal solution for you. This is a clear liquid material that is kind of like a gel that you dab on with the applicator and then cure in short time with the UV LED that comes as part of the applicator kit. You can build up a layer at a time around your cord to encase it in a sturdy sleeve. In fact this may work best to just eliminate the electrical tape all together and use the Bondic in its place.

I have and have used Bondic for a few repairs and buildups. I have no affiliation with the company what so ever. I can say a few things about the product though:

1. Do not mistake the product as a glue. It is not a glue at all.
2. It will adhere to rough surfaces well but not well to many smooth surfaces.
3. Despite the above items, which may very well be mentioned in the company literature, do not be misled by some off the Bondic videos and Internet Ads that give you the impression that it is the best glue on earth. It is not glue.
4. The Bondic material, once cured with the UV light is hard and tough and supposedly very strong.
5. I have tried the material on things like broken clay or pottery mug handles and the fix works as long as you build up material all the way around the handle seam and cure it. Any material that is down tight in the rough and fit together joint just does not get cured in there and so a simple butt joint fix like you may use with epoxy or CA glue just does not work with Bondic.
6. One cool thing about the material is that as long as you keep the applicator in its opaque metal box that it comes in you do not have to worry about the stuff going to waste like so often happens with partially used CA glue tubes.